# AxesLabel a List, without braces

Tags: plotting, display

How can I use a list of variables (possibly subscripted) as an [`AxesLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html) without showing the braces.

For example,

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

would look the same, just without the braces on the y-axis label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, Row[{Subscript[y, 1], " ", Subscript[y, 2]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That was easy, thanks!  My example might have been too minimal, in that I want it to work automatically for arbitrary length lists.  Using `Riffle` takes care of that: `Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, Row[Riffle[{Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2],Subscript[y, 3]}, ", "]]}]`

Answer (score 6):

I propose a slightly different form of [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html):

> Row[list,s] inserts s as a separator between successive elements.

And as [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) commented:

> The front end has special handling for `","` as the second argument of `Row`, so that it automatically adds space after the comma as long as the comma isn't the last character of a line.

```
labels = {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2]};

Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, Row[labels, ","]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Slicker than my `Riffle`!

Comment: The front end has special handling for "," as the second argument of Row, so that it automatically adds space after the comma as long as the comma isn't the last character of a line. So, I would recommend `Row[labels, ","]` instead.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the usage tip!

Answer (score 2):

Another way：

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[Subscript[y, 1] Subscript[y, 2]]}]
```

or

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, 
       Graphics[{Text[
          HoldForm[Subscript[y, 1](*","*)Subscript[y, 2]], {0, 1}]}, 
        ImageSize -> 35]}]
```